# How do I add an array of images in an album using Photos framework in IOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, photos

I'm trying to integrate DKImagePicker into my app, because it simply looks better. When the user selects an album I want the app to save the images the user chose, in a new folder that I've created. Here is how I'm attempting to handle the save:

```
...

@IBAction func openAlbum(sender: AnyObject) {

  // pickerController is  DKImagePickerController 

  pickerController.didSelectAssets = { [unowned self] (asset: [DKAsset]) in
    print("didSelectAssets")
    self.transferSelectedAssetsToAlbum(asset)
  }
  self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func transferSelectedAssetsToAlbum(assets: [DKAsset]) {
  PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

  // Here I want to save all items in assets in the album
  for asset in assets {
    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(asset.fullScreenImage!)
    let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)
    albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
  }

  }, completionHandler: {
    success, error in
    print(success)
    print(error)
  })
} 

...
```

When running this Xcode, it complains saying `'NSFastEnumeration' cannot be used with array litteral`. I understand this is because of `albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaholder])` should not be under `for .. in` loop. But, I want to save every image in the assets? How can I make it work without a for loop?

Hopefully, I made that clear enough. If not please let me know so I can clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error is misleading. All that was missing to make this work is `!` for `assetPlaceholder`. So all I did was replace `albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])` with `albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder!])`